# Button поверх TextView

Tags: android, xml, textview

Добрый день. Есть простая разметка с `TextView` и `Button`.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LL2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_below="@+id/LL"        >


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/selected_item2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     >
</TextView>       
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LB"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"                >
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom" />

</LinearLayout>
```

`Button` изменяет размер `TextView`. Как сделать, чтобы `button` располагался внизу, не деформировался при изменении размера текста, не съезжал вниз, исчезая с экрана, и был как бы наложен поверх `TextView`?

Полная разметка xml

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LL"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Кнопка  1"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:id="@+id/button" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Кнопка 2"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:id="@+id/button2" />

</LinearLayout>



<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LL2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_below="@+id/LL"        >


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/selected_item2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     >
</TextView>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LB"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"                >
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Первые 2 кнопки находятся сверху под `actionbar`. Но проблема лишь с тем, что сверху описал - с `button3` и `textview`.

Comment: посмотрите в сторону `RelativeLayout`, он должен помочь вам в достижении вашей задумки.

Comment: `TextView` и `Button` помести во `FrameLayout`. А тут как задашь расположение `Button`, и больше оно не поменяется.

Comment: Всем спасибо. RelativeLayout помогло. 

Уверен, что способ Maksim Ponomarev тоже рабочий. Благодарю.